# What are biological primary mathematical skills?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, terminology, evolution, mathematical-ability

In doing a bit of background reading for [this question](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/629/why-most-of-the-inventors-are-men) I came across a section in the book [Cognitive Neuroscience: The Biology of the Mind](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393927954) on page 602 stating:

> There are no sex-related differences in biological primary mathematical skills, even in nonhuman primates

And later defines *secondary* mathematical skills as

> the kinds of math taught in schools in the industrialized world

But it doesn't define what *primary* mathematical skills are.

Can anyone explain what is meant by the term?

<sub>Cognitive Neuroscience: The Biology of The Mind, 2nd ed. M. S. Gazzaniga, R. B. Ivry, G. R. Mangun.</sub>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The term seems to come from David C. Geary's 1995 article. Here's the abstract with full-text link below:

> An evolution-based framework for understanding biological and cultural
>   influences on children's cognitive and academic development is
>   presented. The utility of this framework is illustrated within the
>   mathematical domain and serves as a foundation for examining current
>   approaches to educational reform in the United States. Within this
>   framework, **there are two general classes of cognitive ability,
>   biologically primary and biologically secondary**. Biologically primary
>   cognitive abilities appear to have evolved largely by means of natural
>   or sexual selection. Biologically secondary cognitive abilities
>   reflect the co-optation of primary abilities for purposes other than
>   the original evolution-based function and appear to develop only in
>   specific cultural contexts. A distinction between these classes of
>   ability has important implications for understanding children's
>   cognitive development and achievement.

You can read more about David C. Geary's articles on mathematics on [his website](http://web.missouri.edu/~gearyd/articles_math.htm).

#### References

- Geary, D. C. (1995). Reflections of evolution and culture in children's cognition: Implications for mathematical development and instruction. American Psychologist, 50, 24-37. [FULL TEXT](http://web.missouri.edu/~gearyd/GearyAP.htm)